# c# MySQL like query not taking parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using a query to find keywords in a particular field, when i put the @parameter and then addparameter with value it does not work, however when i input the value directly, it works, anyone can help me pass value as parameter to my query please? below are my codes:

This works and retrieves any record with the word "My" in its title.

```
string cmdText = "SELECT  * FROM tblshareknowledge where title LIKE '%My%'";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myTitle", title);
```

This one does not work:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT  * FROM tblshareknowledge where title LIKE '@myTitle'";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myTitle", title);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're currently putting your parameter within quotes, which means it's no longer being used as a parameter. I suspect you want:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM tblshareknowledge where title LIKE @myTitle";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myTitle", "%" + title + "%");
```