# search on listview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Well I'm new in winform , I wanna do a search on a listview but i got some error, here's my code:

```
public void delete_view_list()
{
    for (int i = list_data.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
         list_data.Items[i].Remove();
    }
}

public void search(string nama)
{
    delete_view_list();
    string sql = "select * from barang where Nama_barang like concat('%', nama , '%')";
    list_data.View = View.Details;
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adap.Fill(dt);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
        ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["ID"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["code"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Nama_barang"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Jumlah_barang"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Harga_awal"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Harga_jual"].ToString());
        list_data.Items.Add(listitem);
    }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = search_box_fill.Text;
    search(name);
}
```

Is there something wrong on there?

Comment: **some error** what is that error??

Comment: on adap.fill(dt) , i got MySqlException was unhandled ....

Comment: Side note: You're not using `nama` variable passed to the method.

Comment: just a reminder:  check if `name` variable is null or empty to handle future error you will probably  face.

Comment: Hello,i'm the SQL parametrized querys nazi. **ALWAYS USE PARAMETRIZED QUERYS**.It solves all this problems,and also [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use parameters!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919318/c-sharp-mysql-like-query-not-taking-parameters)

here you have issue in below line, you haven't use the parameter in the sql statement.

```
 string sql = "select * from barang where Nama_barang like concat('%', nama , '%')";
```

it should be

```
 string sql = "select * from barang where Nama_barang like concat('%', "+nama+", '%')";
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
 string sql = "select * from barang where Nama_barang like concat('%', " + nama + " , '%')";
```

or

```
 string sql = "select * from barang where Nama_barang like '%" + nama +"%')";
```

But the recommended way of making the queries is **parameterized queries**

```
string sql = "select * from barang where Nama_barang like @cmdnama";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmdnama", "%" + nama + "%")
```

and recommend would be that you should check if the string is empty before sending to the function like

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string name = search_box_fill.Text;
      if(name.Length >= 1)
           search(name);
}
```

Comment: lol , that's the magic
thanks for the answer :3
you solve my problem