# How to use search logic where like in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

How can I search only the select position and when I type letter in my textbox he only search from the position of the selected item in combobox but my textbox search even other position I want is if I select position and type letter a in my textbox, the datagrid select the position and the first letter of firstname midname lastname like that:

[THE POSITION SELECTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stJIp.png)

[THE BUG OF MY SEARCH TEXTBOX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fCjE.png)

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from employee where Pstatus='Active'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
        else
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `empID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`, `Gender`, `Address`, `Zipcode`, `Position`, `Rate`, `DateHired`, `TelNo`, `empSched`, `Pstatus`, `AllowanceID`, `image`, `Red` FROM `employee` WHERE FirstName LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR MiddleName LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR LastName LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "%' AND Position LIKE '" + comboBox1.Text + "%' ", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `empID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`, `Gender`, `Address`, `Zipcode`, `Position`, `Rate`, `DateHired`, `TelNo`, `empSched`, `Pstatus`, `AllowanceID`, `image`, `Red` FROM `employee` WHERE Position LIKE '" + comboBox1.Text + "%' ", con);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Comment: Please go and read about SQL injection, you are wide open to it here.

Comment: @DavidG so i will go params to prevent sql injection or i will base on the database not in the datagrid ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# MySQL like query not taking parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919318/c-sharp-mysql-like-query-not-taking-parameters)

Comment: Whatever solution you decide on, you **must** use parameters if you are talking to the database. You must **not** use string concatenation.

Comment: how can i params the like %

Comment: Please read the link I provided.

Comment: when i only FirstName like % he work but when i add or middlename and  or lastname in AND position hes not work

Comment: Show us that attempt, with an edit with **extra information** in your question.